# How to transform xml to json and json to xml dynamically in Azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In Azure logic app how to convert xml to json or json to xml based on the requirement.

The data is dynamic i,e they can be in any format. And xpath expression is required to get the required node.

Comment: Can you update the question to describe your actual problem?  You correctly identify the xml() and json() functions which answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions that you said are the correct ones, here is an example to get an xpath value from an input converted in xml:

```
  "Initialize_variable": {
            "inputs": {
                "variables": [
                    {
                        "name": "xpathValue",
                        "type": "String",
                        "value": "@xpath(xml(body('Get_blob_content_using_path')), 'string(/*[local-name()=\"Part\" and namespace-uri()=\"\"])')"
                    }
                ]
            },
```